# Kafka Consumer not Receiving messages

Tags: c#, winforms, apache-kafka, consumer

I use C# on the visual sdudio. I've created two project, one is for Producer and another is for Consumer. I want to send and receive message both on WinForm. At first, I successfully run the Producer Winform. Before run the code I've start zookeeper and kafka like this:

`start zookeeper: zookeeper-server-start.bat ../../config/zookeeper.properties`

`start kafka: kafka-server-start.bat ../../config/server.properties`

and then start consumer like this:

`kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning`

I can send message with the WinForm and receive message with cmd.

```
    string topic = "test";
    consumerMsg = entry.Key + " is: " + entry.Value;

    KafkaNet.Protocol.Message kafkaProducerMsg = new KafkaNet.Protocol.Message(consumerMsg);

    var options = new KafkaOptions(uri);
    var router = new BrokerRouter(options);
    var client = new Producer(router);

    client.SendMessageAsync(topic, new List<KafkaNet.Protocol.Message> {kafkaProducerMsg }).Wait();
```

This picture shows the winform and the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rftNK.png)

However, when I want to use code to replace the cmd, I can't even get data into the consumer.
The code of Consumer is like this:

```
{
    class Program
    {   
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {           
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:9092");
            string topicName = "test";

            var options = new KafkaOptions(uri);
            var brokerRouter = new BrokerRouter(options);
            var consumer = new Consumer(new ConsumerOptions(topicName, brokerRouter));

            Console.WriteLine("on foreach..."); // I use cw to find out how far I go
            foreach (var msg in consumer.Consume())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("in foreach...");
                Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msg.Value));
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I find out that it won't run into the foreach, as `consumer.Consume()`doesn't get any data at all, its null.

So here is my question: did I miss some steps in the Consumer? I searched for many instruction and their code all seems very simple, just as I've showed above. Or is there any other way to run a consumer with code?

Thank you so much guys!

---

Update.

Actually I found this in the output window:

```
Awaiting message from: http://myacount.me.cn:9092/
Received message of size: 36 From: http://myacount.me.cn:9092/
Awaiting message from: http://myacount.me.cn:9092/
Received message of size: 36 From: http://myacount.me.cn:9092/
```

Does this mean the Consumer can get the message but just don't show it?

Comment: Maybe you are in the same Consumer group as the CommandLine consumer, so he is consuming all messages

Comment: I've tried to turn down the cmd but it still won't work.

Answer (score 0):

No sure if it would help, but maybe try also to include:

```
using KafkaNet;
using KafkaNet.Model;
using KafkaNet.Protocol;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I've already include them all. KafkaNet.Protocol is even not been used.